# Delete half of the records from MySQL database table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an unknown number of records. I want to delete half of the records. I don’t care which records are deleted. What’s the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved with an example of why you want to do this, perhaps what you want to accomplish. For instance, do you want to save drive space? Improve lookup times? Is this a personal file on your local machine, or a production database? etc.

Answer (score 28):

```
delete from some_table where rand() < 0.5;
```

This will delete *about* half the records, *most* of the time.

Comment: rand() wont necessairly give you 50% though, especially for smaller datasets. If you're allowed to use two queries, I'd say count the number of rows with the first one and then use a LIMIT on your delete query... but I feel like there might be a way to do it with a single query, however you cannot have subqueries on the LIMIT. So it must have something to do with the table's structure... but that's not given with the question.... hmmmmm

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table; then DELETE FROM table LIMIT rows/2;

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: perfect answer, +1

Comment: @Authman Apatira: even with 2 queries and `COUNT(*)` you couldn't delete **exact** a half rows when for example there is 7 rows total.

Comment: I think this is the best solution (in the case you have a auto_incremented primary key) DELETE FROM `tabletodelete` WHERE id % 2 = 0

Comment: @FabriceKabongo I suggest you to create an answer to the question. The solution is really elegant!

Comment: @rila unfortunately, I can't the question is closed. but thanks!!